# Prestashop deletes part of .htaccess automatically

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I use Prestashop 1.7 and system automatically deletes part of the code from .htaccess from time to time.

```
# ~~start~~ 
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: mydomain.cz
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]


    # Strip Facebook spyware tokens
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =HEAD [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fbclid=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1 [NE,L,R=301,E=limitcache:1]
Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=604800" env=limitcache

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The part that Presta was deleting itself was about the Facebook token.

Answer (score 2):

As @CBroe has said, pay attention to `~~start~~` and `~~end~~` comments.

**Put your custom code in .htacces before or after PrestaShop comments**.
That's because all code between those comments is generated by PrestaShop, so if you write or change anything between those comments, your changes will be lost when regenerating .htaccess

Comment: Thank you for explanation how works ~~start~~ and ~~end~~. Do you have any other idea, what could be wrong in the .htaccess?

Comment: I guess you mean about search engines does not see the web correctly. I don't see anything wrong. How do you know that it happens? This issue needs further info or even open a new question.